# Generalisation of a definite integral $I(a)$ with value independent of its parameter $a$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

When I first met the integral
$$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(1+x^a\right)(1+x)^2}d x,$$
having the value  $ \frac12$, which is decent and independent of $a$.

Then I want to generalised it in a similar way. For any $b\ge 0$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(b) & =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^b}{\left(1+x^a\right)(1+x)^{2b+2}} d x  \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}}{=}  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^ax^b}{\left(x^a+1\right)(x+1)^{2b+2}} d x
\end{aligned}
$$

Averaging them $$
I(b) =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\left(1+x^a\right) x^b}{\left(x^a+1\right)(x+1)^{b+2}} d x =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^b}{(x+1)^{2 b+2}} d x
$$

Using the result of beta function,
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}} d t=B(x,y),
$$
we have $$I(b)=\frac12B(b+1,b+1)= \frac{\Gamma^2(b+1)}{2\Gamma(2 b+2)} $$

For examples, $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(1+x^a\right)(1+x)^2}d x =\frac 12;$$
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\left(1+x^\pi\right)(1+x)^3} d x=\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma(3)}=\frac{\left[\frac{1}{2} \times\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]^2}{4}=\frac \pi{16}
$$

---

Are there any **more** generalisation or interesting definite integral $I(a)$ with value **independent** of $a$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1 + x^a) (1 + x^2)}$$
The substitution $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ yields the equality
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1 + x^{-a}) (1 + x^2)} = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^a \,dx}{(1 + x^a) (1 + x^2)} ,$$
so (for all $a$)
\begin{align*}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1 + x^a) (1 + x^2)}
& = \frac{1}{2} \left(\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1 + x^a) (1 + x^2)} + \int_0^\infty \frac{x^a \,dx}{(1 + x^a) (1 + x^2)}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align*}

More generally, for any $b > -2$ we have
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1 + x^a) (1 + b x + x^2)} =
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 - b^2}} \arccos \frac{b}{2} , & b < 2
\\
\frac{1}{2}, & b = 2 \\
\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2 - 4}} \operatorname{arcosh} \frac{b}{2}, & b > 2 \\
\end{array}
\right.$$
for all real $a$. This example subsumes both the previous one ($b = 0$) and the first example in the question statement ($b = 2$).

**Remark** The change of variable $x = \tan \theta$, $dx = \sec^2 \theta \,d\theta$, transforms the original integral to
$$\int_0^\frac\pi2 \frac{d\theta}{1 + \tan^a \theta} ,$$ which appeared with the red-herring value $a = \sqrt{2}$ in the well-known problem A3 on the 1980 Putnam Exam.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for your story. I want to know more.

Comment: You can find the exam problems and solutions in this A.M.M. article. Not much is said about this particular problem, though. https://math.hawaii.edu/home/pdf/putnam/1980.pdf

Answer (score 0):

**One more**
$$
I(n)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(1+x^a\right)(1+\sqrt[n]{x})^{2 n}} d x=\frac{n \Gamma^2(n)}{2 \Gamma(2 n)}
$$
Proof:

Similarly, we use the substitution $x\mapsto \frac 1x$ and get
$$
I(n)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{\left(x^a+1\right)(\sqrt[n]{x}+1)^{2 n}} d x
$$
Again, taking their average gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1+x^a}{\left(x^a+1\right)(\sqrt[n]{x}+1)^{2n}} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d x}{(\sqrt[n]{x}+1)^{2 n}}\\&=\frac{n}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^{n-1}}{(1+y)^{2 n}} d y, \quad \textrm{ where }y =\sqrt[n]{x}  \\&=\frac n2B(n,n)\\
& =\frac{n \Gamma^2(n)}{2 \Gamma(2 n)}
\end{aligned}
$$